# Getting date from SQL-Database creates error

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I've been trying to get the calibration date from my SQL server database but it doesn't seem to work.

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))  
{ 
$output .= "<tr><td>".$row['businessUnit']."</td><td>".
    $row['productGroup']."</td><td>".
    $row['deviceType']."</td><td>".
    $row['serialNumber']."</td><td>".    
    $row['location']."</td><td></td><td>".
    $row['condition']."</td><td>".
    $row['calibrationDate']."</td><td>".
    $row['itemDescription']."</td><td>
    <input type='checkbox'></input></td></tr>";  
}  
return $output;
```

If I do it like this I get this error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

However when I try to format it like this:

```
$row['calibrationDate']->format('Y-m-d')
```

I get another error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null

I have also tried to convert it to a new DateTime first:

```
$date = new DateTime($row['calibrationDate']);
```

Then I get: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

I don't know if it's relevant to the problem but not all columns have a date in that column.
The datatype in the database is "date" and the format is "Y-m-d". How do I get the date to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve date and time types (datetime, date, time, datetime2, and datetimeoffset) as strings, you must set connection option `ReturnDatesAsStrings` to `true`.

```
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"user",
    "PWD"=>"password"
);
```

Documentation about `sqlsrv_connect()` connection options can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

you should used [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) & [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions

```
$calibrationDate= strtotime($row['calibrationDate']);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $calibrationDate);
```

Comment: This gives me the error: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: first you print `$row['calibrationDate']` and show the result

Answer (score 0):

you can use php strtotime() and date() function like this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(($row['calibrationDate']))."</td><td>".
```